# Where openssl searches for default certificates?

Tags: ruby, windows, ssl, openssl, net-http

Today I faced a problem making `https` request with `ruby` under `windows`:

```
C:\Users\Yuri\_>type 2.rb
require 'net/http'
Net::HTTP.get URI 'https://google.com'

C:\Users\Yuri\_>2.rb
c:/Users/Yuri/programs/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
        from c:/Users/Yuri/programs/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `block in connect'
        from c:/Users/Yuri/programs/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
        from c:/Users/Yuri/programs/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `connect'
        from c:/Users/Yuri/programs/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
        from c:/Users/Yuri/programs/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
        from c:/Users/Yuri/programs/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:582:in `start'
        from c:/Users/Yuri/programs/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:477:in `get_response'
        from c:/Users/Yuri/programs/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:454:in `get'
        from C:/Users/Yuri/_/2.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

So I started investigating. As far as I can tell now, it's because `windows` version of `ruby` doesn't come bundled with `ssl` certificates. I decided to found out where it looks for them. `procmon` said that the script tries to open the following locations:

```
C:\Users\Luis\Code\openknapsack\knap-build\var\knapsack\software\x86-windows\openssl\1.0.0k\ssl\cert.pem
C:\Users\Luis\Code\openknapsack\knap-build\var\knapsack\software\x86-windows\openssl\1.0.0k\ssl\certs\
```

And it turned out this paths are in `libeay32.dll`:

```
c:\Users\Yuri\programs\ruby-2.0.0-p353\bin>strings libeay32.dll | grep openknapsack
OPENSSLDIR: "C:/Users/Luis/Code/openknapsack/knap-build/var/knapsack/software/x86-windows/openssl/1.0.0k/ssl"
C:/Users/Luis/Code/openknapsack/knap-build/var/knapsack/software/x86-windows/openssl/1.0.0k/lib/engines
C:/Users/Luis/Code/openknapsack/knap-build/var/knapsack/software/x86-windows/openssl/1.0.0k/ssl/private
C:/Users/Luis/Code/openknapsack/knap-build/var/knapsack/software/x86-windows/openssl/1.0.0k/ssl
C:/Users/Luis/Code/openknapsack/knap-build/var/knapsack/software/x86-windows/openssl/1.0.0k/ssl/certs
C:/Users/Luis/Code/openknapsack/knap-build/var/knapsack/software/x86-windows/openssl/1.0.0k/ssl/cert.pem
```

So I wonder if there are more sane ways to get this information, like with a small `c` program, or maybe from within the `ruby`? Supposedly, that's determined by the options with which `libeay32.dll` was built. Probably, one can determine it by inspecting the [the source](http://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/openssl/1.0.1c/x509__d2_8c_source.html#l00065), if that's a good link for that. But that's way too difficult for me.

Comment: OpenSSL trusts nothing by default. That's in contrast to the browser model, where nearly everything is trusted out of the box. Because OpenSSL does not trust anything, it does not search for default certificates. In fact, it does not even have a "trusted" cert bundle. You provide the certificates you want to trust. You do it on the command line with `-CAfile` (or perhaps `-CApath`), or via the API with `X509_STORE_new`, `X509_STORE_add_lookup` and friends.

Comment: `SSL_connect` with a return value of 1 is success. See the OpenSSL docs on [SSL_connect(3)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_connect.html).

Comment: @loader First, again what are you getting at with your first comment? Then return value of 1 might be success, but the script stops with exception.

Comment: x-yuri: (1) from your title, "Where openssl searches for default certificates?" - openssl does not search anywhere. (2) from your postst "connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0".

Comment: @noloader (1) as far as I can tell, `openssl` has function `X509_STORE_set_default_paths`, that is it has a notion of default certificates. They aren't used by default, but an application can ask to use them. They are default because there's a certain location where `openssl` expects to find them. Have you got better phrasing for the title? (2) that may be true, but the script stops, it doesn't work. I don't know who's at fault. But apparently the cause is in missing CA bundle.