# How am I supposed to get CA bundle file under windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, ssl, openssl

Today I faced a problem making `https` request with `ruby` under `windows`. More on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330941/where-openssl-searches-for-default-certificates). It appears that's because `windows` version of `ruby` doesn't come bundled with `ssl` certificates. Everybody suggests getting them from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem. But that's vulnerable to `man-in-the-middle` attack. As far as I know, under `linux` `ssl` certificates come with `openssl` package (`ca-certificates`). So it appears to be safe. Are there better options for `windows`?

Comment: OpenSSL trusts nothing by default. That's in contrast to the browser model, where nearly everything is trusted out of the box. Because OpenSSL does not trust anything, it does not search for default certificates. In fact, it does not even have a "trusted" cert bundle. You provide the certificates you want to trust. You do it on the command line with `-CAfile` (or perhaps `-CApath`), or via the API with `X509_STORE_new`, `X509_STORE_add_lookup` and friends.

Comment: @noloader That I understand. What exactly it has to do with the question? Are you hinting at something or just providing some info concerning the question?

Comment: What, exactly, is the question? Apparently I mis-read into what you wrote. I read that you wanted a CA bundle. I claim trusting every CA for any certificate is bad, and you should trust one CA for a particular domain. I think trusting one CA for one domain is a better option for all platforms, and not just Windows.